# Truncated text when text size is increased in extended textview scroller

Tags: android, textview, marquee, scroller

I have a class derived from Android TextView to customize a TextView which scrolls text based on this example:[Original Example Code](http://bear-polka.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/scrolltextview-scrolling-textview-for.html)

My problem is that the text is truncated at different positions depending on the size of the text during the scroll. For example some text that is 90 characters long scrolls fine when the text size is less than 100 but if the text size is set to 240 (so it fills my phones height in landscape mode) the text is truncated at character position 83. The larger the text size the more it gets truncated.

It's almost as if there is some kind of memory limit?

```
ScrollTextView scrolltext;
scrolltext.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, xtextsize);
scrolltext.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
scrolltext.setSingleLine(true);
scrolltext.setEllipsize(null);
scrolltext.setMaxLines(1);
scrolltext.startScroll();
```

and in the class

```
setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
mSlr = new Scroller(this.getContext(), new LinearInterpolator());
setScroller(mSlr);
int scrollingLen = calculateScrollingLen()
int duration = (new Double(((scrollstart.mRndDuration*10)/getWidth())*getText().length())).intValue();
setVisibility(VISIBLE);
mSlr.startScroll(mXPaused, 0, scrollingLen, 0, duration);
```

The problem can be recreated using the [original example code](http://bear-polka.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/scrolltextview-scrolling-textview-for.html) if anyone wants to try and recreate it.

So has anyone got an idea why the text gets truncated at different positions depending on the text size?

my layout

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/ll"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
   <com.test.testing.ScrollTextView
        android:id="@+id/scrolltext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks in advance

Further: When using a different font the point at which the truncation starts changes position when the same text size is used. Still looks like a resources issue but where to increase buffers?

Answer (score 0):

check the textview height during landscape/portrait mode was change and as you set as fill_parent for height. This will just fill the parent the control as device size and if the content was larger than the size then it will not scroll. You can put this view inside scrollview and set the textview height as wrap_content.

Comment: This does not fix the issue which is as the text size is increased the number of characters of the text is truncated. The larger the text size the less of the text string is visible. In my tests at text size 240 it will only display the first 83 characters of my string.